# NAT Problem Fortigate 501e v6.0

Tags: nat, fortigate, fortinet, snat

I created a VIP and am having trouble connecting this VIP to an IPv4 Policy. When I put it into the destination I get an error: "Failed to save some changes: Entry not found." I am trying to create a NAT policy.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

With Fortigates, *Virtual IP* is used for destination NAT. *NAT* is used for source NATing which you probably don't want as well.

Basically, don't activate *NAT* in the policy and use the VIP (or VIP group) as destination.

If that doesn't work we'd need the (sanitized) config or GUI screenshots of the VIP and policy settings.

Answer (score 0):

In fortigate firewall  in vip configuration public ip is mapped with private ip and this vip

**Example below**

**Inbound traffic policy**

`Source interface : outside interface Source address : Any Destination interface : inside interface Destination address :Vip Ports: Security profiles:on`
*This vip we are doing destination nat*

*It should work if you are getting error means .. please share screen shot*